# Odd jQuery animate top/height/position bug in firefox and opera

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-animate, opera, jquery-hover

Getting a really odd bug with jQuery animate in Firefox/Opera, have searched and searched but not been able to find a fix anywhere on the interwebs.

Basically what I have is a list of boxes that I want to expand upwards on hover, which works but it in FF/O the boxes not being hovered are 'pushed down' by the same measurement as the hovered box moves up.  Everything functions as expected in Safari, Chrome - not tested IE yet as this bug has stopped me in my tracks.

I've set up a jsFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/VMjxR/5/ - and code is pasted below.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>1</li> 
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
        $("li").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"height": "170px", "top": "-140px"});
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"height": "30px", "top": "0px"});
    });
    });
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    height: 30px;
    margin-top:200px
  }
ul li {
    width: 30px;
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    background:red
  }
```

Comment: Ooops, kinda forgot the most important part! Edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `float: left` instead of `display: inline-block` on your list items. Then make sure to add a `margin-right` to your list items to space them apart, and add `list-style: none` to your `ul` to hide the bullets.

```
ul {
  height: 30px;
  margin-top:200px;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  width: 30px;
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background:red;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VMjxR/6/).

Comment: Your answer is perfect, I was just asking the wrong question. The list is in a fixed position footer have update your fiddle to reflect this, now there's a weird jumpy animation/movement going on - http://jsfiddle.net/VMjxR/8/

Comment: You sir are a star.Thanks very much.